# Calculate the limit of the following function

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to4} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2-x^{0.5}}{x}\right)}{2x^{0.5}-x}?$$

I hope to get some explanation since I'm stuck on this for hours.

**Edit:** I got 3 different suggested answers, which is right?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin right deleted my comment, But still 2 of 3 here are wrong or maybe 3

Comment: Did you follow the link in the comment below my answer?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! The answer is 1/8 — I corrected my mistake and arrived at the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ we have $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$ and therefore $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan x}{x}=1$.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to4} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{x}}{x}\right)}{2\sqrt{x}-x}=
\lim\limits_{x\to4} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{x}}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}\left(2-\sqrt{x}\right)}=
\lim\limits_{x\to4} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{x}}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x^3}\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{x}}{x}\right)}=
1\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}=\frac18$$

Comment: Why I have three answers everyone with different result?

Comment: See the limit on [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+arctan%28%282-sqrt%28x%29%29%2Fx%29%2F%282*sqrt%28x%29-x%29+as+x-%3E4). However, this doesn't prove me right.)

Comment: I saw it thanks, But yet looking at the other suggested answers they are right too

Answer (score 0):

It might simplify the problem to use the following substitutions:

Let $2-x^{0.5} = z$, $x = (2-z)^2$, and $x^{0.5} = 2-z$

(Note: this means $\lim_{x\to4}$ is equivalent to $\lim_{z\to0}$)

Plugging in we get: $$\lim_{x\to4} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2-x^{0.5}}{x}\right)}{2x^{0.5}-x} = \lim_{x\to4} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2-x^{0.5}}{x}\right)}{(2-x^{0.5})x^{0.5}} = \lim_{z\to0} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{z}{(2-z)^2}\right)}{z(2-z)}=\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)}{2z}$$

We then apply L'Hôpital's rule by differentiating the numerator and denominator separately: $$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)}{2z} = \lim_{z\to0} \frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1+(z/4)^2}}{2} = \frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: Each one of you gave something different

Comment: First equation line second term should be $\lim\limits_{z\to0} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{z}{(2-z)^2}\right)}{z\color{red}{\sqrt{x}}}$

Comment: Ah, my bad. The answer should be 1/8 as you wrote

Answer (score 0):

First, let $x=y^2$ and then $y=z+2$ which make
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{x}}{x}\right)}{2 \sqrt{x}-x}=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y-2}{y^2}\right)}{(y-2) y}=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{(z+2)^2}\right)}{z (z+2)}$$ Now, compose Taylor series
$$\frac{z}{(z+2)^2}=\frac{z}{4}-\frac{z^2}{4}+O\left(z^3\right)$$
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{(z+2)^2}\right)=\frac{z}{4}-\frac{z^2}{4}+O\left(z^3\right)$$ Now, long division to get
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{(z+2)^2}\right)}{z (z+2)}=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{3 z}{16}+O\left(z^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approched.